# What is best way to write e2e test on windows and expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to write end to end test for my react-native mobile application. But i don't know which test framework should i use. I found 3 frameworks but i have 2 problems; Expo and Windows...

1. **Detox;** I don't have mac i cannot use this framework.
2. **Cavy;** It's too much nested with normal code. And i need export my classes like that; `export default hook(Scene);` at the end of code. But i'm using `withNavigation()` function on some pages for use navigation at child components.
3. **Appium;** I don't know if it usable with expo. I searched for it but couldn't find a way to use with expo. And it's looks so complicated to me.

Does anyone know better solution for write end-to-end tests with react-native on windows and expo?

Comment: Were you able to find any e2e frameworks that worked with Expo? What did you end up doing?

Comment: @C.Kelly i got some other troubles about expo and decided to use react-native-cli. So i'm not using expo anymore

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not using Expo, Cavy should work w/ Expo.

https://cavy.app/docs/getting-started/running-tests

```
If you're using Expo, cavy run-ios or cavy run-android will fail to successfully build your app.

Build your app separately and run your tests using:

# To test on iOS
cavy run-ios --skipbuild

# To test on Android
cavy run-android --skipbuild

Copy
Passing in the --skipbuild option means that cavy-cli will assume your app is already running, and will wait for your test results.
```